# sh + how to send cntrl c and then enter yes to accept license

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, perl

I need to enter CNTRL C and then I need to enter `yes` , in order to accept license

*now I am thinking how to automate this process*

can we automate this process as run the sh script and entering `CNTRL C` and then enter yes ?

```
sh  CentOS-7.0.1406.libcurl.20180621.x86_64.sh
                   LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR ZVELODB SDK LIBRARIES

IMPORTANT, READ CAREFULLY: THIS ZVELODB SDK LIBRARIES LICENSE AGREEMENT
("LICENSE AGREEMENT") IS A LEGAL AGREEMENT BETWEEN YOU (EITHER AN INDIVIDUAL OR
A SINGLE ENTITY, IDENTIFIED HEREIN AS "YOU" OR "YOUR") AND ZVELO, INC.
("ZVELO") FOR THE ZVELODB SDK LIBRARIES ("ZVELODB") AND OTHER PROPRIETARY
SOFTWARE REQUIRED FOR THE PROPER INTEGRATION OF ZVELODB ("ZVELODB SOFTWARE").
ZVELO IS WILLING TO GRANT YOU THE FOLLOWING LIMITED, NON-EXCLUSIVE,
NON-ASSIGNABLE, REVOCABLE LICENSE TO USE THE ZVELODB SOFTWARE ACCORDING TO THIS
AGREEMENT ONLY ON THE CONDITION THAT YOU ACCEPT ALL TERMS IN THIS AGREEMENT.
BY INSTALLING OR USING ZVELO SOFTWARE YOU ACKNOWLEDGE THAT YOU HAVE READ THIS
LICENSE AGREEMENT AND THAT YOU AGREE TO BE BOUND BY THE TERMS OF THIS LICENSE
AGREEMENT. IF YOU DO NOT AGREE TO THE TERMS OF THIS LICENSE AGREEMENT, ZVELO IS
NOT WILLING TO LICENSE THE ZVELODB SOFTWARE TO YOU AND YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED
TO USE THE ZVELODB SOFTWARE.

The zveloDB Software is protected by copyright laws and international copyright
treaties, as well as other intellectual property laws and treaties.
Unauthorized reproduction or distribution is subject to civil and criminal
penalties.

1.    GRANT OF LICENSE.

zvelo grants You the right to use the zveloDB Software only in conjunction with
the validly signed Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA) between zvelo and You.

2.    RESTRICTIONS.

You may not use, copy, modify, or transfer the zveloDB Software, or any copy
thereof, in whole or in part, except as expressly provided in this License
Agreement or as defined under a separate zvelo License Agreement. You may not
reverse engineer, disassemble, decompile, or translate the zveloDB Software, or
otherwise attempt to derive the source code, algorithms, or data files of the
zveloDB Software, or authorize any third party to do any of the foregoing. You
may not use data returned ("RESULTS" or "CATEGORIZATIONS" or "META-DATA") from
zveloDB Software to extend or enhance other software or products, unless
otherwise agreed to in writing by an authorized representative of zvelo. You
may not use the zveloDB Software for any software development, application
deployment and/or ultimate production purpose. Except as expressly permitted in
the previous two sentences, any attempt to transfer any of the rights, duties
or obligations hereunder is void.  You may not rent, lease, loan, resell for
profit, or distribute the zveloDB Software, its results, or any part thereof
except as expressly provided in this License Agreement or as defined under a
separate zvelo License Agreement. You agree to comply with all applicable laws
regarding the use of the zveloDB Software.

3.    YOUR RESTRICTIONS.

You agree:

    3.1.    to make all payments due to zvelo in a timely fashion;

    3.2.    to notify zvelo promptly by email at servicedelivery@zvelo.com if
            You suspect unauthorized use of the zveloDB Software and that You
            remain responsible for such unauthorized use;

    3.3.    not to resell, assign, transfer, or delegate this License Agreement
            or Your rights or obligations under it without the prior written
            consent of zvelo and that any attempt to do such an assignment
            without prior written consent is void;

    3.4.    not to alter the controls of a hard drive or computer system to
            enable the use of the zveloDB Software after termination of the
            license;

    3.5.    that You are responsible for the value obtained from Your use of
            the zveloDB Software;

    3.6.    that You will implement or install the zveloDB Software only in an
            operating system environment and upon such equipment as approved by
            zvelo;

    3.7.    that You are not a specifically designated individual or entity
            under any U.S. (or other) embargo or otherwise the subject, either
            directly or indirectly, to any order issued by any agency of the
            U.S. Government (or any other government) limiting, barring,
            revoking or denying, in whole or in part, Your export privileges
            and that You will notify Us immediately in the event You become
            subject to any such order;

4.    RENEWAL AND TERMINATION.

    4.1.    Without prejudice to any other rights, this License Agreement will
            terminate immediately without notice if you fail to comply with the
            terms and conditions of this License Agreement. Upon notice of
            termination, you agree to immediately cease all use of the zveloDB
            Software and destroy all copies of the zveloDB Software and its
            results.

5.    OWNERSHIP.
.
.
.


  11. BECAUSE THE PROGRAM IS LICENSED FREE OF CHARGE, THERE IS NO WARRANTY
FOR THE PROGRAM, TO THE EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW.  EXCEPT WHEN
OTHERWISE STATED IN WRITING THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND/OR OTHER PARTIES
PROVIDE THE PROGRAM "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED
OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  THE ENTIRE RISK AS
TO THE QUALITY AND PERFORMANCE OF THE PROGRAM IS WITH YOU.  SHOULD THE
PROGRAM PROVE DEFECTIVE, YOU ASSUME THE COST OF ALL NECESSARY SERVICING,
REPAIR OR CORRECTION.

  12. IN NO EVENT UNLESS REQUIRED BY APPLICABLE LAW OR AGREED TO IN WRITING
WILL ANY COPYRIGHT HOLDER, OR ANY OTHER PARTY WHO MAY MODIFY AND/OR
REDISTRIBUTE THE PROGRAM AS PERMITTED ABOVE, BE LIABLE TO YOU FOR DAMAGES,
INCLUDING ANY GENERAL, SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES ARISING
OUT OF THE USE OR INABILITY TO USE THE PROGRAM (INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
TO LOSS OF DATA OR DATA BEING RENDERED INACCURATE OR LOSSES SUSTAINED BY
YOU OR THIRD PARTIES OR A FAILURE OF THE PROGRAM TO OPERATE WITH ANY OTHER
PROGRAMS), EVEN IF SUCH HOLDER OR OTHER PARTY HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.

                     END OF TERMS AND CONDITIONS
Do you agree with the License? [yes/no]
```

what I did until now is that:

```
  sh  CentOS-7.0.1406.libcurl.20180621.x86_64.sh < < trap ctrl_c INT >/dev/null < <(echo y)
```

but this approach isn't working

Perl/python one liner lines are also expected

**example of expected results:**

```
Do you agree with the License? [yes/no] yes
Extracting . . .
lib-4.0.20-20180619.x86_64.rpm
lib-devel-4.0.20-20180619.x86_64.rpm
Extract completed.  Continue installation by installing the RPM
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

**what I can say is that when I run the script and do CNTRL C then I get imminently the Question  about yes**

Comment: At which point do you need to press 'Ctrl-C'? In other words, which command did you originally call that forced you to take this "detour"? The output you showed implies that the `sh CentOS...sh` call immediately gives you the license to accept; I didn't see where the 'Ctrl-C' takes place ...

Comment: on the first point immediately after I run the script

Comment: I think you should provide text of CentOS-7.0.1406.libcurl.20180621.x86_64.sh to see which part is required to be interrupted with Ctrl-C.
Ctrl-C has different behaviour in interactive and execution modes, so possible your "CentOS-7.0.1406.libcurl.20180621.x86_64.sh" should have an option to accept license from batch, or you can modify it.

Comment: I can say that , only we need is first to send ( CNTL C ) , and then yes , thats all

Comment: I agree with @AdminBee : I think you *think* you need ctrl-C, not because it is needed, but because of the solution you tried to apply. This is known as a "XYProblem": you ask for a solution to Y, but in reality need to fix the problem X. focus on what you *need* (answering y to the licence question), and not on the 1 solution path you are trying to use to solve it (which may not be the best, most concise, most portable, etc).

Comment: @OlivierDulac come on, I haven't used that installer, but it wouldn't be the first thing that won't let you accept or reject the terms until you fully scrolled the text down (ahem "read" it in full). Or killed the process piping to the pager with Control-C ;-)

Comment: @Uncle Billy : ok, I can agree with that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use [`expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) for such tasks.

But, as a quick and dirty kludge, you can use `script(1)` as a mini-expect:

```
{ sleep .3; printf '\003'; sleep .3; printf 'y\r'; ...other prompt responses...; } |
script -q /dev/null -c 'sh that_installer.sh'
```

`\003` is Control-C, `\r` is Return/Control-M, etc.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe `yes ' qy' | script -q ....` (would be curious if someone would try that one ^^. `Space` to go further, `q` to try to quit (if that pager expects a q only at the end), and then `y+newline(done by yes command)` next to feed the answer.) Or much shorter (and "saner"), if the pager is "less" or "more" (or something similar) : `printf 'Gq' ; printf 'y\n' | script....` . (`G` should go to the end, `q` should quit) . maybe `export PAGER=less` can force the pager used to be less? This isn't code golf though, so I +1 your solution instead of proposing those as a solution