# sed + delete all lines between two matching patterns and instead of them add a word as x=yes

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

here example of script

when I did successfully deletion between two matching patterns ( the first is `cat <<EOF | more` and the second is `read x` )

the script

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<EOF | more

.
.
.
.


EOF

echo -n "Do you agree with the License? [yes/no] "
read x

.
.
.
```

my sed command

```
sed -i '/^cat <<EOF | more/,/^\read x/d' test.sh
```

now I want to add to sed ability to add the parameter x=yes insted of all deletion lines as above

is it possible to add this ability in my sed command ?

example of expected results

```
#!/bin/sh

x=yes
```

Comment: sed is a line based tool, try gnu sed extensions

Comment: Ar you proposing deleting the license agreement from an installation script? Isn't that illegal?

Comment: It does appear to be related to your recent question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675807/sh-how-to-send-cntrl-c-and-then-enter-yes-to-accept-license

Comment: related but much diff, its diff situation and diff question

Comment: @they why would this be illegal?  Even if you believe in some rather dubious copyright-maximalist theories (actually, "theories" is a very generous term - more accurate would be "crazy assertions" that would also make it illegal to write your name in, or scribble in, or even underline words in a book you bought) about what you're allowed to do on your own computer or with your own copy of a copyrighted work that you bought, what yael wants to do is automatically answer "yes" to accept the license terms.

Comment: @cas In this case it is not about automating the acceptance of the terms, but to remove the displaying of the terms. If you read the terms in their other question, you see that without accepting the terms, you are not allowed to use the software. By installing the software, you acknowledge that you have *read the terms*.  Only, you haven't, because the terms were deleted by this guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `a`ppend command to append text:

```
sed -e '/^cat <<EOF | more/ax=yes' -e '//,/^\read x/d'
```

At least with GNU `sed`, it is executed even if the line itself gets deleted. You only want to append it once, so just use the first address for `a` and the range for `d`. The empty expression repeats the previous expression.

Comment: we get /usr/bin/sed: can't read /^cat <<EOF | more/ax=yes: No such file or di

Comment: @yael then you must have mis-typed the sed command because it works exactly as Philippos said it does.....which I'm slightly surprised by because I would have assumed that `ix=yes` would have been required instead of `ax=yes`, so that `x=yes` gets inserted **before** the block of text about to be deleted rather than inside it.  nope, it works anyway.

Comment: @cas Inserting before nothing should be the same as appending after nothing, was my idea. (-: